# Laravel 7 does not display flash message

Tags: php, laravel, session

```
Laravel Framework 7.25.0
PHP 7.2 on LARAGON
```

I'm not sure if it has anything to do with it, but I believe it may be something related to my routes, I may be talking nonsense.

No flash message is being displayed, I was only able to display a message by setting it to Session::put, retrieving it in the view and then deleting it.

```
Session::put('success', 'example');
return redirect()->route('example', array('id_example' => 'example'));
```

When I use with, withErrors, flash on the front always returns null.

```
return redirect()->route('example', array('id_example' => 'example'))->with('success', 'Text');
or
return redirect()->back()->withErrors( ['example'] );
or
Session::flash('success', 'example');
```

In the view I've tried several ways, all of them have the same result. EXCEPT when I use Session::put manually to store the return message.

```
@if (Session::has('error'))
@if ($errors->any())
@if (Session::has('success'))
@if (session()->has('success'))
```

This is my model that I use on routes.

```
Route::namespace('Front')->group(function(){
    # Homepage
     Route::get('/', 'ExampleFrontController@Home')->name('home');
})

Route::namespace('Admin')->group(function(){
    # Login
     Route::get('/admin/login', 'ExampleAdminController@Index')->name('admin.login');
})
```

I have no problem using Session :: put, however, the returns from my Form Requests Rules are also not displayed and this is causing me a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After asking the question, I decided to take a test that I had not yet done.

I commented on the kernel the class: StartSession::class and ShareErrorsFromSession::class.

As planned, the sessions stopped working.

In my case, I had to move both classes from $ middlewareGroups to $ middleware, this solved my problem above.

I changed that:

```
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

for this

```
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        #    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        #    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        #    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

Comment: Thanks I had a session problem for an expired 401, but with this it was solved